# GNUPlot select rows in Histogram

Tags: row, gnuplot, histogram

I have a Data file which looks like the one below. Now, I wanted to make a histogram chart using column 9, column 10 as errorbars.  That works out pretty good. Bubt is there an option only to plot specific rows?

I tried the solution in a another thread that using a ternary operator:

`plot 'Härte StS-123 bis 151.txt' using ( (  $0 == 4 || $0 == 6 ) ? $9 : 1/0 ):($9+$10):($9-$10):xticlabels(2)`

this  plots row 4 and 6 indeed, but leaves an empty space inbetween the datasets.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Data File:

---

StS-123a    "SBR / THF" 50.10   49.60   49.20   50.70   50.00   49.50   49.85   0.49    0.00974176

StS-123b    "SBR / THF" 51.00   50.40   50.40   52.00   52.80   50.60   51.20   0.90    0.017614257

StS-124a    "SBR+2phrGraphit"   49.60   49.40   49.30   48.90   49.40   49.10   49.28   0.23    0.004599753

Answer (score 1):

What you may want is the `index` option to the plot command:

```
plot 'datafile' index 4 u 9:($9-$10):($9+$10):xticlabels(2), \
     '' index 6 u 9:($9-$10):($9+$10):xticlabels(2)
```

This should plot just the data from the 4th and 6th datasets (rows), albeit with two different styles which you can adjust in the plot command.

Did you want to connect the values from the two datasets?  That may be trickier.

If you want to only plot data from the 4th and 6th rows that have data, you can use external commands in gnuplot, like:

```
plot "<sed '/^$/d' data.dat | sed -n '4p; 6p'" u 9:($9-$10):($9+$10):xticlabels(2)
```

(This may not be the most compact way to use sed in this case, but it deletes blank lines then returns the 4th and 6th rows.)

Comment: Thank you. That kinda fits it. Allthough - I have to have to newlines inbetween each row. But I have Data where sometimes there's a whiteline in between sometimes not. I thought there might be a way to plot just certain rows as they are listed in $0. And then, if I have a new plot command everytime it screws up the whole diagramm - which you could work around. I just thought maybe there's a way to do this which I don't know of. I guess I'll have to modify the datafile by hand then, it's not too much data but the other way would have been more beautiful....

Phil

Comment: Do you just want to plot data from two rows, from a file which may or may not have whitespace between each row?  I don't know how to do this in native gnuplot, but see my edit for a way to do that using an external command.